# Draw custom view depending on current state

Tags: android, view, drawing

What I want to do is simply changing the colors of my view depending on its state, normal, focused, or pressed. I don't know how to do this, maybe I should simply call `onDraw` when the view is clicked, keeping trace of the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the state of the view and simply override the onDraw() method to perform your drawing using the canvas objects according to the view state.The view should invalidate itself or else you can call invalidate() when the view state changes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What do you mean with invalidating the view?

Comment: so I should override onTouchEvent and then from that manage the state of the view and call invalidate(), right?

Comment: You can check "Implementing a Custom View" section to understand this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 0):

Make an XML file that handles that and put it in your drawable folder.  Then set the view's background to that.  Here is an example

my_background_selector.xml

```
<!-- 
  Use Drawables
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_background" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_background" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_background"  android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_background"/> -->

<!--
OR Use Color attributes
<item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/dark_blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red"  android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/blue"/> -->
```

Then set the view's background to that file and it will take care of changing states:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_background_selector"
```

Or programmatically

```
view.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_background_selector));
```

Comment: it's not a button, my custom view extends View

Comment: This method should work with any view.  Unless you are working with a canvas or something.  My answer did say button a lot... I edited it.